# Combine select dropdown with input text

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I've read the other answers to my question regarding combining both the select and text fields, but when I try to apply any of the solutions to my form it does not work.

Can someone modify my form so that you end up with a dropdown containing both the select options and a text input field?

Please include the appropriate jquery script as well.

**Here is my form code:**

```
<form id="ajax-contact-form" action="drumming_for_jared_registration.php" method="post">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">

            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputName">Date:</label>
                <div class="controls">                    
                      <input class="span4" type="text" id="inputName" name="Date" placeholder="Date:" style="color:white" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value=''" onFocus="if(this.value =='Date:' ) this.value=''">
                    </div>      
                </div>                  
            </div>
            <div class="row"></div>


            <div class="span4">
            <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="inputName">New To Studio?</label>
                     <div class="controls">                   
                      <select input class="span14" type="text" id="inputLevel" name="New_to_Studio">
                                <option>New To Studio?</option>
                                <option>Yes</option>
                                <option>No</option>
                                </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div class="row"></div>


        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="submit">Send</button>      
      </form>
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: That was close, but I do not want the "autocomplete" option.